# Getting issues while printing parameters for the proc

Tags: tcl

I am trying to create a proc trace method. Means when script will use any proc it will print its procedure name and proceed. To do that I am following this method

```
rename proc _proc

_proc proc {nm params body}  { 
    eval "_proc $nm \{$params\} \{ 
    puts \"Enter proc $nm\";
    puts \"Parameters: $params and body \" ;
    $body;
    puts \"Exit proc $nm\"\}"
}

proc abc { param1 param2 param3 } {
    puts "$param1 and $param2 and $param3"
}
```

When I am calling `proc abc`, it is giving output as

```
Enter proc abc
Parameters:  param1 param2 param3  and body 
a and b and c
Exit proc abc
```

Question: Why this is printing body also as i definition I want only parameters to print

Answer (score 2):

That seems over-complicated to me. Let's get rid of the `eval` and reduce the amount of quoting for starters. (Omitting the rest of your code for simplicity.)

```
_proc proc {nm params body}  { 
    _proc $nm $params \
        "[list puts "Enter proc $nm"];
        [list puts "Parameters: $params and body "];
        $body
        [list puts "Exit proc $nm"]"
}
```

But that's not exactly what you want, is it? You want to print the actual parameters and not the formals. That's rather more complex.

```
_proc proc {nm params body}  { 
    set cmd "[list puts "Enter proc $nm"];puts \"Parameters: "
    foreach p $params {
        append cmd "[lindex $p 0]=\$[lindex $p 0], "
    }
    append cmd " and body \";"
    _proc $nm $params $cmd$body\;[list puts "Exit proc $nm"]
}
```

But even that will go wrong horribly once you start trying to have a meaningful result returned from the procedure. While you could do something horrific with `catch` and `return` to make it work (and it's easier in 8.5, and much easier with 8.6's `try`…`finally`), **you want a different approach**. You want execution traces.

```
_proc proc {nm params body} {
    _proc $nm $params $body
    trace add execution $nm enter [list track_entry $nm $params]
    trace add execution $nm leave [list track_leave $nm]
}
_proc track_entry {nm params real args} {
    puts "Enter proc $nm"
    foreach formal $params actual [lrange $real 1 end] {
        append p " [lindex $formal 0]=$actual,"
    }
    puts "Parameters:$p and body"
}
_proc track_leave {nm args} {
    puts "Exit proc $nm"
}
```

If we try that, we see we get *very* informative output and yet we don't “disturb” the procedure's working:

```
% abc p d q
Enter proc abc
Parameters: param1=p, param2=d, param3=q, and body
p and d and q
Exit proc abc
% info body abc

    puts "$param1 and $param2 and $param3"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Just a question: In line `_proc track_entry {nm params real args}` you have mentioned 3 parameters (nm, param, real) but where you are calling `track_entry` you are passing 2 paramteres. How?

Comment: @Nitesh Trace callbacks add extra arguments when they are called.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to write a replacement for the `proc` command that allow tracing and introspection features to be injected. However, the best way to go about it is probably to use the `trace` command to attach tracing hooks to a procedure, and let those hooks invoke `info` commands to list things like parameter lists, procedure bodies etc.

Comment: Can you provide me link where i can get this info

Comment: @Nitesh: if you let your mouse pointer hover over the highlighted words "trace" and "info", you will find that they are clickable links to pages documenting those commands. If you visit http://wiki.tcl.tk and use the search box, you will find still more information on them.